# Scaling FBCTF server installation and decoupling logic and data storage from a single node?

Tags: mysql, facebook, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

Our team installed the FBCTF server on our node using installation guide in their documentation, but we are not able to find a starting point about how to install MySQL or PostGreSQL on another node and configuring FBCTF with that server installation.

Any guidance or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance SO guyz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal production installation when you enter into directory `/var/www/fbctf/` you get file named `settings.ini`.  Here you can change the server location of mysql server and username and password can also be changed from here.